# How to create DropDownMenu in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to create a `DropDownMenu` using `SwiftUI`. Finally I created a `DropDownMenu` where there is a problem the immediate next following siblings of this `DropDownMenu`'s `VStack` moved from it's default position when it's expanded also the `VStack` height increase dynamically. Please find the view as following:

[image]

Actually I need a real `DropDownMenu` as usually we are use to in **Desktop Application**. Have a look of my code as following:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

public struct DropDownMenu: View {
    @State var expanded: Bool = false

    public var body: some View {
        let marineGreen : Color = Color(UIColor.parse(0x346C7C))
        let whitishGreen: Color = Color(UIColor.parse(0xE7EEEF))
        let genders: [String]   = ["Male", "Female", "Unknown"]
        let width  : CGFloat    = 140

        let menu = VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Text("Gender").fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(whitishGreen)
                Image(systemName: self.expanded ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down").resizable().frame(width: 13, height: 6).foregroundColor(whitishGreen)
            }.onTapGesture {
                self.expanded.toggle()
            }.frame(width: width)
            if (self.expanded) {
                ForEach(0 ..< genders.count, id: \.self) {
                    self.menuItem(genders[$0], width, whitishGreen)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding().frame(width: width)
        .background(self.expanded ? marineGreen.opacity(0.9) : marineGreen)
        .animation(.none)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.expanded.toggle()
        }
        return menu
    }

    private func menuItem(_ gender: String, _ width: CGFloat, _ color: Color) -> some View {
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        let height : CGFloat = 20

        return VStack {
            Divider().background(color)
            Button(action: {self.expanded.toggle()}){
                Text("\(gender)").frame(height: height).padding([.leading, .trailing], padding)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: width).contentShape(Rectangle())
            .foregroundColor(color)
        }
    }
}
```

Extension of `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    static func parse(_ hex: UInt32, alpha: Double = 1.0) -> UIColor {
        let red   = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
        let green = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(hex & 0xFF)/256.0
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

I expect your help to resolve this issue and hope it would be highly appreciable too.

Comment: Not sure I understood what's wrong with this menu. It is opened and properly drawn... Probably it is a matter of usage for this menu. If you need to have it dropped over other UI elements then just use `ZStack` and `alignmentGuide` to stick it to some location.

Comment: I modified the last line of `body` of `DropDownMenu` as same as `return ZStack{ menu }.frame(width: width, height: 40, alignment: .topLeading)` . It's dropped over to the other UI Elements. But no hope for `TapGesture` Event. As because `DropDownMenu` stayed behind of next UI Elements. Another things is I'm not clear to the concept of `alignmentGuide`. Need co-operation from expertise.

Comment: Please don't implement gender selection as a 3-option dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video, it has a nice walkthrough that should be exactly what you (or others coming to this page later) want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwD4cScGCq8

Comment: If you want a `DropDown` and it's your only application then it's okay! Otherwise it's no longer feasible to use like a `DropDown` or `ComboBox` with the combination of other component! If you've overcomes such difficulties then you are welcome. It's might be helpful but not the solution.